# SQL selecting the max DENSE_RANK() value and then average

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, dense-rank

I would like to modify the query below so it only keeps the highest VISIT_flag value grouped by CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE and then average VISIT_flag by CUSTOMER_ID.

I'm having challenges figuring out how to take the maximum DENSE_RANK() value and aggregate by taking the average.

```
(
SELECT  
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    TRANS_TO_DATE ,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY HOUR - RN)  VISIT_flag
from  (
    SELECT  
        CUSTOMER_ID,
        TRANS_TO_DATE,
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$')) HOUR,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$'))  ) as RN
    FROM  mstr_clickstream                                
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE, REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$')
)
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Should be simple by using another enclosing query. You use ROW_NUMBER in a subquery and then use DENSE_RANK on the result of this subquery... now you could simply add another query which uses the DENSE_RANK query as subquery and simply add a `max(VISIT_FLAG)`.

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic in order to get the last VISIT_flag, meaning the last "visit" occured within a day, you must order (within the DENSE_RANK) descending. Though descending is solving the problem of getting the last visit, you cannot calculate the average visits of customer because the VISIT_flag will always be 1. So to bypass this issue you must declare a second DENSE_RANK with the same partition by and ascending order by in order to quantify the visits of the day and calculate your average. So the derived query

```
SELECT customer_id,AVG(quanitify) FROM (
SELECT  
customer_id,
trans_to_date ,
DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY HOUR DESC, RN DESC, rownum)  VISIT_flag,
DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY HOUR ASC, RN ASC, rownum)  quanitify FROM  (
SELECT  
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    TRANS_TO_DATE,
    TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$')) HOUR,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$'))  ) as RN
FROM  mstr_clickstream                                
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE, REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$') )) WHERE VISIT_flag = 1 GROUP BY customer_id
```

Now to be honest the above query can be implemented with easier way without using DENSE_RANK. The above query makes sense only if you remove GROUP BY customer_id from outer query and AVG calculation and you want to get information about the last visit. 
In any case you may find below the easier way

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,AVG(cnt) avg_visits FROM (
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE, count(*) cnt FROM (
    SELECT  
        CUSTOMER_ID,
        TRANS_TO_DATE,
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$')) HOUR,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$'))  ) as RN
    FROM  mstr_clickstream                                
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE, REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOUR,'\d+$'))
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_TO_DATE) GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

P.S. i always include rownnum in dense_rank order by statement, in order to prevent exceptional cases (that always exists one to the database :D ) of having the same transaction_time. This will produce two records with the same dense_rank and might an issue to the application that uses the query data.